# Find control with similar id using j query

Tags: jquery

I have a javascript object ($(this)) and i want to find the dropdown control whose id contains "Day". Also, i need to find text area control (id doesn't matter). I have tried this below code but it doesn't work.

```
$(this).find('select[id=*"Day"]')
$(this).find('input[type="text"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('select[id*="Day"]');
$('textarea').val();​
```

Those both work: http://jsfiddle.net/Czhh9/4/

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.

But this code does the search for the full document and not DOMElement. I need to find it in particular javeobject without affecting any other controls with similar id's and textarea controls.
.

Comment: I got it worked using:

$(this).find("textarea") 
$(this).find('select[id*="Day"]')